# Where are Cache settings stored?

Tags: 7, configuration

I assumed the settings from the function [system_performance_settings](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.admin.inc/function/system_performance_settings/7) were stored in variables, but couldn't figure out which.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you trace the code from the system_performance_settings, you'll see that is uses system_settings_form for form generation, which uses system_settings_form_submit form submit handling, which in turn does

```
foreach ($form_state['values'] as $key => $value) {
  if (is_array($value) && isset($form_state['values']['array_filter'])) {
     $value = array_keys(array_filter($value));
  }
  variable_set($key, $value);
}
```

So to find any individual variable name, your best bet is to

```
drupal_set_message($key);
```

in that function.

Comment: lazyweb has changed :P thanks for the info, that worked fine for me!

Comment: Glad it helped. Hopefully the approach is useful for finding variables for other system settings as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
cache: 0
cache_lifetime: 0
page_cache_maximum_age: 0
block_cache: 0
page_compression: 0
preprocess_css: 0
preprocess_js: 0
```

Those were the results of @Letharion answer, disabling everything in the form.